# Draw tangent edges with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am trying to produce axonometric drawings with three.js, hoping for something like Rhinoceros 3D's Make2D output.

Using white meshes on white background with polygonOffset and black edges with a threshold angle works great, but lacks the edges where curved surfaces are tangent to the camera, as seen on the cylinder in the example below.

Is there anything in the library to draw these edges? If not, what would be the best way to compute them?

```js
// materials
const line_mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({"color": 0x000000}),
    // prevent Z-fighting
    mesh_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        "polygonOffset": true,
        "polygonOffsetFactor": 1,
        "polygonOffsetUnits": 1
    }),

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-2, 2, 2, -2, 0.1, 1000),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

add_to_scene(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), 1);
add_to_scene(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(.5, .5, 1, 32), -1);

scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera.position.z = 5;
renderer.setSize(600, 600);

animate();

function add_to_scene(geometry, x_offset) {
    const obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mesh_mat);
    obj.position.x += x_offset;

    // use a threshold angle to get rid of unnecessary edges
    const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(obj.geometry, 20);

    obj.add(new THREE.LineSegments(edges, line_mat));
    scene.add(obj);
}

function animate () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe [an outline](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=out#webgl_postprocessing_outline)?

Comment: Thank you. However, my understanding is that this requires one rather expensive pass per object (to have outlines when objects overlap), and doesn't work on concave objects.